# Graphing the cumulative average per top k% value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame `df` sorted by `value` in a descending order:

```
value       gender       age
3015        male         10
2519        male         30
2397        male         15
...
1           male         12
1           female       10
1           male         9
```

- `value` consists of `int` larger than `0`.
- `gender` consists of `str` data: `male` or `female`.
- `age` consists of `int` larger than `0`.

I have two objectives:

1. Graph the proportion of `female` per top k% `value`. (Hence, the graph should have the k% `value` for the x-axis and the proportion of `female` for the y-axis.)
2. Graph the average `age` cumulatively for `female` per top k% `value`. (Hence, the graph should have the k% `value` for the x-axis and the average `age` of `female` who qualify for that `value` for the y-axis.)

**A more thorough explanation on Task 2:**

For the top 20% `value`, for instance, I would first of all determine which `value` corresponds to the top 20%. Then, I would count all data points with `value` either equal to or greater than the top 20% `value` with `gender == 'female'`, as well as cumulating their `age`. Finally, I would plot the average `age`, calculated by the cumulated age divided by the number of counted `female` data points.

---

I have completed the first task using `np.arange()` and `np.cumsum()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_gender = df['gender'].to_numpy()
cumulate_df_gender = np.cumsum(df_gender == "female")

plt.plot((np.arange(len(df))*100)/len(df),
         cumulate_df_gender/np.arange(1, len(df)+1), color='black', lw=3)
```

[image]

I tried replicating my method for my second task, but I was unable to do so as `np.cumsum()` only takes one column cumulatively and I cannot take the average of a different column simultaneously.

Any insights on how to tackle this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's figure out how to plot top-k mean.

The cumsum divided by `[1,2,3,4, ..., n]`, is equivalent to `[mean(x[:k+1]) for k in range(n)]`. Let's define this as a function

```py
def cummean(x):
    return x.cumsum() / (np.arange(1, len(x) + 1))
```

Then we if we are given a sorted vector we can plot the `cummean` of the flipped vector `cummean(x[::-1])`. The x axis will be simply the k value `(1 + np.arange(n)` converted to percentage by multiplying by `100% / n`.

```
def plot_topk_mean(x):
    n = len(x)
    plt.plot(100 * (1 + np.arange(n)) / n, cummean(x[::-1]))
```

Your first query is achieved by sorting by values transforming the gender to `1` where it is `female` and `0` where it is `male`, by using `['gender'] == 'female'`.

```py
plot_topk_mean(df.sort_values(by='value')['gender'] == 'female')
```

[image]

For the second query we have to take the rows of `df` where `df['gender'] == 'female'`, we state it as `df[df['gender'] == 'female']`. Just to be save we `sort_values(by='value')`, and finally take the `age` column, by `['age']`.

```py
plot_topk_mean(df[df['gender'] == 'female'].sort_values(by='value')['age'])
```

[image]

### About the data I used:

Notice that I synthesized some data to create the plots, basically I ran this code before the lines before plotting.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame();
df['value'] = np.random.rand(1000) * 3000;
df['gender'] = np.where(np.random.rand(1000) < 0.1, 'female', 'male')
df['age'] = np.random.rand(1000) * 30
```

Comment: Works like a charm; to complete the Task 2, I changed the final `'value'` to `'age'` so that it is `plot_topk_mean(df[df['gender'] == 'female'].sort_values(by='value')['age'])`.

Comment: This was some months ago, but as I was reviewing the code today, I may have found an issue; shouldn't the `sort_values()` in `plot_topk_mean` be ordered in a descending order? In other words, shouldn't there be `by='value', ascending=False`? Proceeding without it will order it in an ascending fashion.

Comment: Isn't that why I passed `x` flipped to cummean (`x[::-1]`)?